# Why does my Perl script work fine in Windows but not in Ubuntu?

Tags: perl

My Perl script works fine in Windows command line;but, I couldn't run it in Ubuntu. I tried with a simple Perl script but it is giving me error message:

```
can't open perl script "testl.pl" inpute/output error.
```

Here is the script I used to test and save it as test.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "content-type: text/html \n\n";
print "hello worrld\n";
```

Can any one help me fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You ran a script `test.pl`, but you didn't run the one that you posted.  You apparently ran a script that is in your PATH, while the script you posted is not in your PATH.

There's nothing in the script that you posted that will produce the output you posted in your question.

The script you posted works fine in Ubuntu.  These are the things you need to ensure when running a script in Ubuntu.

### Running Scripts in Linux

#### You can call the script using the interpreter's name. In this case:

```
$ perl test.pl
$ perl /home/user/test.pl
```

This will run the script that is either currently in the same directory where the command is call or found in the Path variable.  This method will not search the `PATH` variable.  If the script is not located in the current folder you have to give a full pathname for the script to be executed.

The script does not need to have the shebang (`#!/usr/bin/perl`) header.

#### Setting the execute bit

You can set the exec bit with:

```
$ chmod +x test.pl
```

In conjunction with the execute bit set, it will also need the shebang header.  If the exec bit is set the script can be called by it's file name.  It will only run a script that is found in the `PATH` variable.  The first one located by the order in the PATH will be executed.  Unlike Windows which you said works, by default (and for security reasons) **the current directory `.` is not in the user's path and will not be searched**.  You can check your path variable by running:

```
 $ echo $PATH
```

The script will execute if it's located in one of these (among others) default path search locations:

```
~/bin
/usr/local/bin
```

If the script is not in a directory of the PATH variable you have to specify the full pathname to run it:

```
$ ./test.pl
$ /home/userid/test.pl
```

#### Identifying which script is being located

You can check the location of a script that is being run with this command:

```
$ type test.pl
```

That will show you the full pathname of the first `test.pl` script located.  If there are multiple scripts in different PATHs you can display all of them with this command:

```
$ type -a test.pl
```

In this case if there are multiple scripts by the same name, calling the script by the full pathname would be the best method.  A script by such a common name as `test.pl` should always be called by the full pathname to ensure the correct one is being executed.

Comment: Hi James thank you for your response. The first one was a spelling error. I tried all but still resulted the same error. I tried to find the path for the script using "type test.pl" and gave me " test.pl not found" though it is already there. I think it couldn't recognized the file, I do not know why.

Comment: what do you get when you type `./test.pl`?

Comment: I got "input/output error"

Comment: Will you edit your question and copy/paste the output of `cat test.pl` to it?

Comment: gave me the same error

Comment: I don't see the output in your question.  Edith your question and put the output of this command: `cat test.pl`.  When you copy and paste the output, include the command with what you copy and paste to your question.

Comment: Sorry I don't know to copy and past in ububtu ?

Comment: Which OS can you copy and paste in?  I don't use a Mac, but you copy and paste in Ubuntu the same way you do in Windows.  Hold the Left button of the mouse while you move the cursor to select what you want to copy.  Then right click on what you hav`e selected` and `click copy`.  Then go to your question, click `Edit`.  Right the cursor at the bottom of the text in your question.  Then click `Paste`.

Comment: Sorry I went out. I don't know if there is any my application but I can't select or copy and past in Ubuntu.

Comment: @Kiflu It's not possible to point out your exact problem without seeing exactly what is on your screen.  The commands and output that you are describing can't be reproduced.  The only way that `cat` would show what you have typed is if that is that is the content of the `test.pl` file.  Without coping and pasting we can't see the content of the files that you are dealing with.